# What else should I do to run my asp.net core application?

Tags: debian, deployment, asp.net

I want to deploy my **mvc** `asp.net core` application on debian server.
What I have done so far:

1. Installed `dotnet-runtime-5.0`
2. Installed `dotnet-sdk-5.0`
3. Downloaded my application from git to server

Now, I am able to run the application using `dotnet run --project /application` and I get this message:
[image]

But when I try to connect to the server on port 5000, it says **server refused the connection**. When I try `curl localhost:5000` from server itself, it returns nothing.

What else should I do ?

**EDIT:** I edited my source code and now, I can reach the page using curl from the server itself. However I still cannot connect to the server from LAN.

Comment: Your server is listening to both 5000 and 5001 is the reason you are not using 80 (HTTP) or 443 (HTTPS)?

Comment: Well, I will use reverse proxy later, but first I want to try if the app is working properly without reverse proxy.

Comment: Can you provide the part of the code where you start listening for connections? Have you bound to localhost interface (127.0.0.1)?

Comment: Please don’t post text as images, it is not accessible. Instead, use code blocks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server is only listening on `localhost`. That means it cannot be reached over the network. If you want it to be reachable, you need to change this, for example using the `--urls` command line parameter.

You can find more details in the [official documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel/endpoints?view=aspnetcore-5.0).

It could look like this:

```
dotnet run --project /application -- --urls http://*:5000
```

Comment: You are right. It was configured only for localhost in the source code of application. Changing it to "*" fixed the problem.